# Доступ к mongoDb серверу

Tags: mongodb, windows-server, windows-server-2012

У меня есть *vps*-сервер (*Windows Server 2012 R2*), я там развернул базу *mongoDb*, сделал всё как в инструкциях (запустил как службу).

Вот конфиг:

```
logpath=c:\mongodb\log\mongo.log
dbpath=c:\mongodb\data\db
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017
```

Служба работает, данные на сервере в базу пишутся, читаются, в общем база работает.
Открыл порт 27017 и на exe файлы моно тоже разрешил доступ.

Я пытаюсь подключиться к базе с другого компьютер (ну в общем достучаться до сервера) и у меня это не получается.
В итоге я проверил порт, с помощью команды `telnet` и мне говорит, что не удаётся открыть соединение:

> C:\Users\xxxx>telnet xxx.xx.xx.123 27017
>   Connecting To xxx.xx.xx.123...Could not open connection to the host, on port 27017: Connect failed

На сервере запустил команду для проверки портов `netstat -an`

В ней указано следующее:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

как я понимаю, это означает, что порт открыт.

В общем, помогите пожалуйста достучаться до сервера, что ещё можно или нужно сделать для этого. Сервер кстати доступен, у меня там есть папка зашаренная, я в неё попадаю без проблем, там же развёрнут *SQL*-сервер и он работает отлично.

P.S. Просто никогда не занимался настройкой серверов и *mongodb* первый раз использую.

[image: Скриншоты]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `bind_ip` можно убрать совсем. По умолчанию MongoDB будет слушать [все адреса](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp).

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

В конфиге должно быть

```
bind_ip=0.0.0.0
```